# In Linq for Entity Framework, what is the best practice for returning a resultset by querying multiple columns for a search string?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am writing a generic search query inside a EF5 repository that will search multiple columns for a specific string.

In SQL we would simply use a`WHERE Col1 LIKE '%string%' OR Col2 LIKE '%string%'` etc.

This is the code I have currently:

```
var members =
            Query()
                .Where(
                    x =>
                        x.Phone1.Contains(searchText) || x.Email1.Contains(searchText) ||
                        x.Phone2.Contains(searchText) || x.Email2.Contains(searchText) ||
                        x.FirstName.Contains(searchText) || x.LastName.Contains(searchText) ||
                        x.Fax1.Contains(searchText) || x.Username.Contains(searchText) || x.Address.Contains(searchText)

                        );
        return members;
```

Now by my reading, that should work... but its not. So I got to thinking... There must be a better way. Some progressive multi-step building of the output possibly? But I have no idea how to go about that in a resource friendly way. Any kick in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your code example does not return a *ResultSet*, it returns an unexecuted `IQuerable<T>`.

Comment: what does `Query()` return?

Comment: It's unclear to me whether you're asking why your current code "doesn't work" or whether you're concerned with performance, or readability of code, or what? Can you clarify what question you're trying to get answered?

Comment: Yes my bad, I am firing off the .ToList() in another method.

Comment: What I was looking for is another way of combining the different where clauses to make it cleaner. The example I gave here is pretty simple... but we have some entities that need to search 100+ fields in some rare cases, and it gets pretty ugly.

Comment: Damn guys. I feel like a total tool. Some asshat on my team changed my connection string. I was test-querying one database and the entities were pulling from another that had been emptied. It was always returning 0 rows when I KNEW there was data. I finally did a Query().ToList() directly and when that got no results I found the cause. Sorry to waste your time.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, above you need to query an entity. Something like:

```
var members = dbContext.YourEntity            
            .Where(
                x =>
                x.Phone1.Contains(searchText) || x.Email1.Contains(searchText) ||
                x.Phone2.Contains(searchText) || x.Email2.Contains(searchText) ||
                x.FirstName.Contains(searchText) || x.LastName.Contains(searchText) ||
                x.Fax1.Contains(searchText) || x.Username.Contains(searchText) || x.Address.Contains(searchText)
                ).ToList();
```

This is identical to the SQL query you mentioned above.

To improve on this you may need to restructure you database. You could create a relational entity where your phone numbers are in one entity, emails in other and so on. These would link back to your members, You would then be querying fewer fields (but the same amount of data).